# What does comma in Python mean?

Tags: python

I am trying to learn backward propagation in pytorch, where I saw this code:

```
def backward(ctx, grad_output):
        """
        In the backward pass we receive a Tensor containing the gradient of the loss
        with respect to the output, and we need to compute the gradient of the loss
        with respect to the input.
        """
        i, = ctx.saved_tensors
        grad_output = 2*i
        return grad_output
```

I cannot understand what `i,` is here.

Comment: In this specific context, it means `ctx.saved_tensors` is a sequence of exactly one value, and `i` is being assigned to the first value.

Answer (score 5):

Python can unpack values, e.g if we have a tuple

```
t = (2,3,'wat')
```

we could assign its values to variables like this

```
coolnumber, othernumber, word = t
```

which would lead to `word` being set to `'wat'`.

If our tuple has length one, we need to distinguish between assigning the whole tuple to a variable

```
a = (1,)
# a is now (1,)
```

and unpacking that one value

```
a, = (1,)
# a is now 1
```

Answer (score 1):

`i,` is a 1-tuple whose sole element is `i`, just like `i, j` is a 2-tuple (obviously, can't just write `i` because that's not a tuple, but just `i`). When on the right side of an assignment, such syntax is used to construct a tuple; when on the left side, the assignment will deconstruct a tuple (or another sequence) into components. See this example:

```
# construction
scalar = 5          # => 5
two_tuple = 6, 7    # => (6, 7)
one_tuple = 8,      # => (8)

# deconstruction
five = scalar
six, seven = two_tuple
eight, = one_tuple
```

So, if `ctx.saved_tensor` is a 1-tuple, your code will assign the content of `ctx.saved_tensor` to `i`.

(Note that you will often read that the tuple syntax includes parentheses — `(6, 7)` instead of `6, 7`. This is half-correct; tuple syntax does not include the parentheses, but they are necessary in many contexts because the comma has a very low priority, or because you want to delimit the commas inside a tuple and those outside of it, like in a function parameter list, or within another sequence. That said, the extra parentheses do not hurt.)